# Java regular expression to capture repetive groups

Tags: java

I am not able to capture all the data including all chars ,digits, spaces and special characters from group 2 through regular expression

tried regular expressions

```
 final String regex = "^:(.*?)//(.*[\\s\\S]?)";
    String line1 = ":Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall";
    String line2 = "//Humpty Dumpty had a great fall";
    String rhyme = line1 +  line2+"\n"+ "ssdsds"+"\n";
    final String value = rhyme.replaceAll(regex , "$2");
 final boolean formatIdentified =   rhyme.matches(formatRegex);
System.out.println(formatIdentified);//returns false
```

value I am expecting

```
"Humpty Dumpty had a great fall
 ssdsds
"
```

corrected regular expression should work with format `:abc//xxxx`, output should be `xxxx`.

Comment: The "value I am expecting" is an example of input? I don't see any colons `:` there so the regex obviously cannot match because it starts with `^:`

Comment: What is the actual output you get?

Comment: I get the expected output using your code

Comment: its not working edited my code

Comment: @Giacomo Alzetta : that is expected out , string rhyme is the input

Comment: why rhyme string not matches with above regular expression?

Comment: rhyme.replaceAll(formatRegex, "$1"); this is returning "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wallssdsds" , it should return only "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible that`String.replaceAll` and `String.matches` are handling the terminator for multi-line strings differently, i.e. newline vs end of the string, which is why `value` may print the expected result but `matches` prints false.

I would be more explicit and use `Pattern` and `Matcher` directly rather than proxied through String:

```
        String rhyme =
                ":Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall\n" +
                "//Humpty Dumpty had a great fall\n" +
                "ssdsds\n";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^:(.*?)//(.*[\\s\\S]?)", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rhyme);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("[Pattern not found]");
        }
```

This will output:

```
   Humpty Dumpty had a great fall
   ssdsds
```

If you are expecting to only match up to a new line ending you just need to change the flag to Pattern.MULTILINE.

```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^:(.*?)//(.*[\\s\\S]?)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Which will output:

```
   Humpty Dumpty had a great fall
```

Answer (score 0):

This provides the output you wanted.

```java
      // ignore everything up to // and then include // and all following
      // in capture group 1.
      final String regex = ".*(//.*)";
      String line1 = ":Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall";
      String line2 = "//Humpty Dumpty had a great fall";
      String rhyme = line1 + line2 + "\n" + "ssdsds" + "\n";
      final String value = rhyme.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
      System.out.println(value);
          // or the follwing if you want the double quotes.
      System.out.println("\"" + value + "\"");
```